# Python FileExistsError: [Errno 17] when using `open("...", "r")` on a file (no mkdir)

Tags: python, file, filesystems, nfs, strace

I'm running into a weird error which many people seem to happen in a completely different context. In the cases I've found, it's mostly related to `mkdir` being called with a path where a file exists.

But in my case, I'm simply calling `open("meta.yml", "r")` on an existing text file. The stacktrace clearly points to the line which just calls `open`, specifically

```py
  File "some-path/experiment.py", line 348, in deserialize
    with open("meta.yml", "r") as f:
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'meta.yml'
```

The function itself is trivial

```
def deserialize() -> "Experiment":
    with open("meta.yml", "r") as f:
        contents = f.read()
        obj = yaml.load(contents, Loader=yaml.Loader)

        # ...
```

and the error happens on the line with the `open` call.

I am quite certain both that the file exists, and that there is no directory with the same name. **What is important to note is that this does not fail 100% of the time.** I'm essentially executing the code in a loop (with a few second sleep in-between), and it takes quite a while for the exception to occur. There is no other process accessing this file, and so far every time I've let it run for a while, say an hour, I got the failure (sometimes sooner).

I've managed to run the failure through strace and here's the last few calls just before the failure

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/37871/stat", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, TCGETS, 0x7ffcabed25a0)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(4, "37871 (polkitd) S 1 37871 37871 "..., 8192) = 175
read(4, "", 8017)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".lockfile", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_CLOEXEC, 0777) = 4
flock(4, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)               = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "meta.yml", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EEXIST (File exists) # <- here it fails
flock(4, LOCK_UN)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
```

As you can see, the `openat` returns `EEXIST` with a handle -1. What is interesting is that in the same strace there are 60 occurences before this of the same exact syscall returning succeeding. Here's one example

```
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".lockfile", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_CLOEXEC, 0777) = 4
flock(4, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)               = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "meta.yml", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5      # <- here it's ok
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=5194, ...}) = 0
ioctl(5, TCGETS, 0x7ffcabed2ec0)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(5, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
ioctl(5, TCGETS, 0x7ffcabed2ea0)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(5, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
lseek(5, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=5194, ...}) = 0
read(5, "gp_config: !!python/object:bopt."..., 5195) = 5194
read(5, "", 1)                          = 0
close(5)                                = 0
```

Based on the manual page I can't figure out how could this possibly happen. What might be worth noting is that this is on a networked filesystem, though the file is being accessed only from a single process on a single machine.

Comment: Does it work if you create a local copy?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a local copy, but if I run this on say my desktop which doesn't have NFS, it does not happen.

Comment: Then your network NFS is the problem.